# Postgres use xpath_table parsing with xmlnamespaces

Tags: postgresql, xml-namespaces

Can I use `xpath_table` parsing with xmlnamespaces

```sql
drop table if exists _xml;
create temporary table _xml  (fbf_xml_id serial,str_Xml xml);

insert into _xml(str_Xml)
select  '<DataSet1  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSet_LocalMaMC.xsd">
  <Stations>
    <ID>5</ID>
  </Stations>
  <Stations>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </Stations>
  <Stations>
    <ID>2</ID>
  </Stations>
  <Stations>
    <ID>10</ID>
  </Stations>
  <Stations>
    <ID/>
  </Stations>
  </DataSet1>' ;


drop table if exists _y;
create temporary table _y as
SELECT * 
FROM xpath_table('FBF_xml_id','str_Xml','_xml',
              '/DataSet1/Stations/ID',
              'true') AS t(FBF_xml_id int,ID text);
select * from _y
```

If I take of the xmlnamespaces it works fine.
I thought to work with Xpath, but when there is null, it gives me wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Postgres 10 or later, `xmltable()` is the preferred way to do this.

You can easily specify a list of namespaces with that.

```
SELECT fbf_xml_id, xt.id
FROM _xml
  cross join 
      xmltable(xmlnamespaces ('http://tempuri.org/DataSet_LocalMaMC.xsd' as x),
               '/x:DataSet1/x:Stations'
               passing str_xml
               columns 
                  id text path 'x:ID') as xt
```

Note that in the XPath expression used for the `xmltable()` function, the tags are prefixed with the namespace alias defined in the `xmlnamespaces` option even though they are not prefixed in the input XML.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=893105ce7289fdd570921805a3afa311)

Comment: Sorry, Works Great!